# Transform not working when parent's height is set in viewport units

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, viewport, viewport-units

I'm having problems with vertical centering. The `header` has a height of `100vh`, and its child element, `site-info`, has an unspecified height. The `site-info` element is supposed to be vertically centered within `header`.

I've tried the standard `transform:translateY` solution, but it doesn't work. `Top:50%` does work, but it's like the `transform` doesn't happen. I can see with FireBug that the `transform` property is attached to `site-info`, but nothing happens.

I've also tried using `vertical-align: center` on `site-info` with no success, and using some `position:absolute` solution for the `header` makes it disappear completely. Using `position:absolute` on `site-info` does not help either.

HTML:

```
<header>

    <div class="site-info">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
background-position:top center;
background-size:100%;
background-size:cover;
height:100vh;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
color:white;
overflow:hidden;
}

div.site-info{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
top: 50%;
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/h8L1ovvg/

Comment: I found out that there was a conflict with animate.css, "FadeInUp", which I also used here. Thanks for the jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in a comment to my question, the issue was a conflict with `animate.css`; the `FadeInUp` animation.

I tried to vertically align the parent `div` with transform. I also wanted it to animate so I applied `FadeInUp` to it, without knowing that `FadeInUp` also used `transform`, causing conflict.

I solved the conflicting `transform` by applying the `FadeInUp` animation to the children (`h1` and `p`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your parent container's height, you can use line-height and vertical-align in tandem as your child's display is inline-block:

```
header {
    background-color:grey;
    background-position:top center;
    background-size:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    height:100vh;
    line-height: 100vh; /* -- same as height -- */
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.site-info {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1; /* -- reset to 1 as it will naturally inherit parent's enormous value -- */
    vertical-align: middle; /* -- This will work now -- */

   /* top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);*/
}
```